# how to write trigger which will generate new schema for new department entry?

Tags: postgresql

I have to write a trigger that will generate a new schema and in each schema, there should be two fixed tables.

when a new department will be registered the trigger should make a new schema and also it should make the same two tables in every schema with their constraints.

Comment: What exactly should trigger the trigger?

Comment: now everything is in the public schema and there is also a department_registration table in public schema so as there is an entry in the department_registration table a new schema should be generated on the department name and two tables should be generated with their privileges and constraints.

Answer (score 0):

That could be a simple row level trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION make_schema() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('CREATE SCHEMA %I', NEW.department_name);
   EXECUTE format ('CREATE TABLE %I.tab1 (...)', NEW.department_name);
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER make_schema AFTER INSERT ON department_registration
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE make_schema();
```